# How do I code for different versions of iPhone OS in XCode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, avaudioplayer

I seem to have a bug because I'm using `-[AVAudioSession setActive:withFlags:error:]` in an iPhone project that is for 3.0 - 4.0.2. So I guess I need to put one of those #IF lines in, so I can get it to do different things based on the OS version... But I can't find out how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply have to check if the method you're trying to call really exists:

```
if ([AVAudioSession respondsToSelector:@selector(setActive:withFlags:error:)]) {
   // call it
}
```

Comment: Just for the record though, I had to change it to [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] respondsToSelector: ... etc.